# Search for people by department?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search, people-search

I am trying to figure out how to setup a user-friendly search for people by department. Preferably, this module should populate automatically from AD (I have user sync enabled already) but I have run into a snag. I have SharePoint Server Foundation 2013 and it appears that the built-in People Search or Enterprise Search isn't available in foundation. I am not sure if it is an option at this point to upgrade for this functionality and am looking for a way to mimic this in foundation. I have found [this article on SharePoint Config](http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2013/05/how-to-create-a-simple-sharepoint-2013-people-directory/) that is EXACTLY what I want but not available for me to use.. sadly. I have also found [this freeware that I can't actually get to work from infowise](https://www.infowisesolutions.com/product.aspx?id=PeopleSearchLite) that might be good enough for me, even without pictures.

Honestly, this is a core feature in my opinion and should be fairly simple to implement in all versions of SharePoint. I am sure there is a way but I just can't seem to find an answer. What does everyone else do for this functionality?

Any help would be great! Thanks!

EDIT: I was toying with just using the org chart from MySites but I also cannot figure out how to implement it on another site. I see people have done it by adding a web part that they call "Org Chart Web Part" but I don't see that in my list of options. I assume it is also because I am using foundation. After some toying, my Org Chart at "mysites.example.org/OrganizationView.aspx" now only shows the one employee and doesn't seem to pull their managers correctly! I don't see what I did to mess it up, but I am running a full sync again to try and fix it. (fixed, something was wrong with my bi-synchronous settings, I'll fix it later)

EDIT2: I still have not found anything to help me with this one. Basically, I just need a web part or app (preferably cheap or free, as I work for a library) that can query AD/MySites and then list out people in the department. Preferably, I could make a specific query for each department page but if it just listed departments and let my users choose that is fine too. Looking into things like SharePoint Groups at this point, I believe those can then pull from AD and possibly then by queried with some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the features you are asking for are supplies by the User Profile Service which includes User Profile Synchronization, Org Chart Web part, and, when connected to the SharePoint Search Service, People Search.

You COULD try to emulate all of this in Foundation, but it will be a frustrating experience. You need SharePoint Server Standard at a minimum for your requested features.

Comment: I have marked yours as the answer. I did find a few ways to do something similar but in the end we upgraded to enterprise. It was already in the budget anyway apparently but the guy that downloaded it got the wrong one, ha. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I tell the truth and I appreciate you not down voting the answer just because you don't like it! :)